# Get DrawingContext size

Tags: c#, wpf, render

Is there a way to get size by having only `DrawingContext`?

I know there is `ClipToBounds` property, does that means what `DrawingContext` size is *unlimited* and has to be specified in addition if matters?

If answer is "it is impossible to get size", then how does rendering occurs? To example

```
// pretty long line
dc.DrawLine(pen, new Point(-100000000, 0), new Point(10000000, 0));
// or geometry with hundreds of lines
dc.DrawGeometry(...);
```

Last one is not a question about `RenderSize` property. It's about how renderer draw points if there are so many of them.

I am making graph control with children figures. They have to render themselves and I'd expect they only need context, but if figure is too big, how should I implement clipping? It is logical, I can check bounds, but question is *which bounds*? Of graph control? And what if `ClipToBounds=false` and figure *should* go out of bounds? This is what I want to know.

For performance reasons using standard wpf figures is not optimal (thousands of points, hundreds of different enclosed areas with different filling, etc.).

---

Graph is FrameworkElement without content. And graph content may be propelled (correct word?) into parent area. Question is how to get bounds to optimize figure rendering, so they don't call Draw methods of `DrawingContext` if coordinates are out of bounds? Imagine 1000000 items to go through for a single render, while knowing bounds may cause skipping some of them.

Comment: "how renderer draw points if there are so many of them". `DrawLine` draws a single line, not a set of individual pixels. WPF is based on vector graphics, not raster graphics. See the [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx) article on MSDN. It has a Vector Graphics section.

Comment: Perhaps you might like to read the [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN if you are interested about these things?

Comment: @Sheridan, thanks, but I still have doubts (I could profile it, but would be nice to know mechanic), shall I rely on *intelligent redrawing* and draw everything (including figures which might never be visible, because they are drawn outside of window bounds), or should I use `VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(parentVisual)` (this actually makes @Clemens answer more clear) to get bounds and clip to those? Or there is no direct answer, but usual "depends" one? =D

Comment: Personally, I would just draw everything... even if it would not be on view initially, the `Visual` could be resized at any time, so it's better to be prepared then to have parts missing.

Comment: @Sheridan, but the maximum size is bounds of window and when visual is resized re-render will occurs anyway, no? I already have feeling, what solution is to pass window size (or use helper methods to get parent window of graph). I just wanted to have official answer. Or nobody here overriding `OnRender` to draw something anymore, but using wpf xaml figures to draw? Oo